# When ng-init in ng-repeat is replays?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple `ng-repeat` to build a HTML list from a javascript array.
Each item can be moved using an input to get the new rank. This input is binded to a variable `rank`. This variable is initialized using the `ng-init` directive.

Code looks like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.getItems()">
  <div ng-init="rank = $index">
    [$index: {{$index}}]
    {{item}}<br/>
    <label>
      Move to
      <input type="number" ng-model="rank"/>
    </label>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.moveItem($index, rank)">
      Ok
    </button>
  </div>
</li>
```

At runtime, when I change the input value and click to the Ok button, function `ctrl.moveItem` is called and item is really moved in the `ctrl.getItems()` array.

So the `ng-repeat` is replayded and items appears in the new order.

**BUT** variable `rank` is not reinitialized and 2 items appears with the same rank.

The sample is here : https://jsfiddle.net/nlips/4ng34b7b/

My question is not so much about moving items in a list, but **I need to understand how ng-init works in the context of ng-repeat**.

I did not find anything on this subject in the AngularJS official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **AngularJS** docs:

> The **ngInit** directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.

Now. You are working with different scope.

[image]

You are using **ngInit** into the *transcluded scope*, overriding *$scope.rank* each time it repeats that portion of template.

If you want to persist your rank you should init it into the **ngRepeat scope**.

Try with:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.getItems()" ng-init="rank = $index">
  [$index: {{$index}}]
  {{item}}<br/>
  <label>
    Move to
    <input type="number" ng-model="rank"/>
  </label>
  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.moveItem($index, rank)">
    Ok
  </button>
</li>
```

**EDITED ANSWER**

Ok, i got it.
The **ngInit** expression is evaluated only when that part of template is going to be rendered into the DOM.

So, when the page is loaded for the first time your expression is fired and each *rank* is evaluated correctly.

But, when you make changes on an item that is already rendered, your template **is not going to be rendered again**, so your ng-init will not be fired.

If you want that *ng-init* to be executed again you have to **remove** the item from the DOM and then append it back, into the new position.

There are several alternatives to this approach, but i hope this clarifies what was going on.

Comment: Sorry Fabio but you have not understood my question. I want that rank is different for each item. The problem is that when I move an item, the rank variable bound to the item being at this position previously, is not reset. Try my jsfiddle.